# Generate all Combinations from Multiple (n) Lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

EDIT: I am completely redoing my questions as I have figured out the simplest way of asking it.  Thanks to the commenters so far that got me thinking about the root problem.

```
public List<string> GetAllPossibleCombos(List<List<string>> strings)
{
    List<string> PossibleCombos = new List<string>();

    //????
    {
        string combo = string.Empty;
        // ????
        {
            combo += ????
        }
        PossibleCombos.Add(combo);
    }

    return PossibleCombos;
}
```

I need to figure out how to recursively go through each `List<string>` and combine 1 string from each list into a combo `string`. Don't worry too much about formatting the string as the "live" code uses a custom object instead. Also, feel free to assume that every list will contain at least 1 string and that there are no null values.

Comment: It's a bit unclear how your code maps on the given problem: the input seems to be a single integer? The output only a list of strings? Can you please provide a more accessible account of your problem. Furthermore: do need to generate all possible combinations at once? Perhaps a lazy implementation is more interesting.

Comment: You might want to read Eric Lipperts series about [Producing combinations](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/)

Comment: The input is just the ID of a template - that template just contains a list of all the tags that the template references. The first part of the code doesn't really matter. It's just there to give a general idea of what is in the Dictionary.  It's the combining all the items in the dictionary that matters.

Comment: Ok. 2) How do you "combine" strings? Do you append them? Do you use a marker in between? Do you have to return a list of lists?

Comment: As far as lazy implementation goes, I am not against it - but I would prefer a generic answer that keeps things simple. Once I wrap my head around the "right" way to do this I will have to convert it back to use my custom objects.

Comment: As my questions shows it doesn't really matter how you want to append the strings as my "final" solution doesn't use them. I just need to figure out how to iterate through all the possible lists to get all the possible combos - using 1 item from each list.

Comment: @juharr - thanks, I read through those but was unable to wrap my head around how to use those algorithms in this instance. The issue being I have n number of lists, and need 1 item from each list.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols: the solution is to use recursion on the number of lists: solve the problem for the base case of one list, and then for the problem with `n` list (by solving it as a merge with the first list and the combination of the onther `n-1` lists).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
class NListBuilder

{
    Dictionary<int, List<string>> tags = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

    public NListBuilder()
    {
        tags.Add(1, new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" });
        tags.Add(2, new List<string>() { "+", "-", "*" });
        tags.Add(3, new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
    }

    public List<string> AllCombos
    {
        get
        {
            return GetCombos(tags);
        }
    }

    List<string> GetCombos(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>> remainingTags)
    {
        if (remainingTags.Count() == 1)
        {
            return remainingTags.First().Value;
        }
        else
        {
            var current = remainingTags.First();
            List<string> outputs = new List<string>();
            List<string> combos = GetCombos(remainingTags.Where(tag => tag.Key != current.Key));

            foreach (var tagPart in current.Value)
            {
                foreach (var combo in combos)
                {
                    outputs.Add(tagPart + combo);
                }
            }

            return outputs;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, don't change you answer to match the "new" question. I am trying to work on converting this over to my "real" system.  It think it will will work.  I will let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: So it took some doing, but my final solution was very similar to yours. I am not sure if it is your code or my conversion but the very first part (`...Count() == 1`) what messing everything up for me. After I took that out it worked great. Thanks for getting me moving in the right direction.

Comment: @Anthony: Working with integral types may lead to shortcuts that can't be applied to objects... Anyhow, you're welcome :)

Comment: Just a note: it is a bad practice to execute time consuming method to property body.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple non-recursive solution that just concatenates the elements of each combination:

```
public static List<string> GetAllPossibleCombos(List<List<string>> strings)
{
    IEnumerable<string> combos = new [] { "" };

    foreach (var inner in strings)
        combos = from c in combos
                 from i in inner
                 select c + i;

    return combos.ToList();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = GetAllPossibleCombos(
        new List<List<string>>{
            new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" },
            new List<string> { "x", "y" },
            new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" }});
}
```

You could generalize this to return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`, which allows the caller to apply any operation they like for transforming each combination into a string (such as the `string.Join` below). The combinations are enumerated using deferred execution.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetAllPossibleCombos(
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> strings)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> combos = new string[][] { new string[0] };

    foreach (var inner in strings)
        combos = from c in combos
                 from i in inner
                 select c.Append(i);

    return combos;
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> Append<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource item)
{
    foreach (TSource element in source)
        yield return element;

    yield return item;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var combos = GetAllPossibleCombos(
        new List<List<string>>{
            new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" },
            new List<string> { "x", "y" },
            new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" }});

    var result = combos.Select(c => string.Join(",", c)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I tried, but could not get this to work with my custom objects. I think (and it's partially my fault for simplifying my question) that my objects are too complex to work with this setup.  The idea is great though and I appreciate you sharing it. I will keep it in mind when I need something like this in the future!

Comment: This should be the answer. A+

Comment: There is a problem with two (and more) characters strings.

Answer (score 7):

In case it helps anyone, here is the method syntax version for Douglas's `GetAllPossibleCombos` method.

```
 public static List<string> GetAllPossibleCombos(List<List<string>> strings)
 {
     IEnumerable<string> combos = new[] { "" };

     foreach (var inner in strings)
     {
         combos = combos.SelectMany(r => inner.Select(x => r + x));
     }

     return combos.ToList();
 }
```

Comment: Nice solution!  I extended and created one for generic object types (see reply)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generic version that works with all object types:

```
    public static List<List<T>> GetAllPossibleCombos<T>(List<List<T>> objects)
    {
        IEnumerable<List<T>> combos = new List<List<T>>() { new List<T>() };

        foreach (var inner in objects)
        {
            combos = combos.SelectMany(r => inner
            .Select(x => {
                var n = r.DeepClone();
                if (x != null)
                {
                    n.Add(x);
                }
                return n;
            }).ToList());
        }

        // Remove combinations were all items are empty
        return combos.Where(c => c.Count > 0).ToList();
    }
```

If you provide null values it will also give you empty combination.  For example:

```
        var list1 = new List<string>() { "1A", "1B", null };
        var list2 = new List<string>() { "2A", "2B", null };
        var output = GetAllPossibleCombos(allLists);
```

Will contain:

[["1A"], ["1B"], ["2A"], ["2B"], ["1A", "2A"], ["1A", "2B"], ["1B", "2A"], ["1B," "2B"]]

Rather than just:

```
        var list1 = new List<string>() { "1A", "1B" };
        var list2 = new List<string>() { "2A", "2B" };
        var output = GetAllPossibleCombos(allLists);
```

[["1A", "2A"], ["1A", "2B"], ["1B", "2A"], ["1B," "2B"]]

Note: *DeepClone* is an extension method used for copying the list. This can be done in many ways

```
    public static T DeepClone<T>(this T source)
    {
        // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace };

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source), deserializeSettings);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that would work for any generic type, comes with a function to convert base-10 to base-n as well.

```
public static class IntExt
{
    const string Symbols = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public static string ToString(this int value, int toBase)
    {
        switch (toBase)
        {
            case 2:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 16:
                return Convert.ToString(value, toBase);

            case 64:
                return Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(value));

            default:
                if (toBase < 2 || toBase > Symbols.Length)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(toBase));

                if (value < 0)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));

                int resultLength = 1 + (int)Math.Max(Math.Log(value, toBase), 0);
                char[] results = new char[resultLength];
                int num = value;
                int index = resultLength - 1;
                do
                {
                    results[index--] = Symbols[num % toBase];
                    num /= toBase;
                }
                while (num != 0);

                return new string(results);
        }
    }
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    public static T[][] GetJoinCombinations<T>(T[][] arrs)
    {
        int maxLength = 0;
        int total = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrs.Length; i++)
        {
            T[] arr = arrs[i];
            maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, arr.Length);
            total *= arr.Length;
        }

        T[][] results = new T[total][];
        int n = 0;
        int count = (int)Math.Pow(maxLength, arrs.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            T[] combo = new T[arrs.Length];
            string indices = i.ToString(maxLength).PadLeft(arrs.Length, '0');
            bool skip = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < indices.Length; j++)
            {
                T[] arr = arrs[j];
                int index = int.Parse(indices[j].ToString());
                if (index >= arr.Length)
                {
                    skip = true;
                    break;
                }

                combo[j] = arr[index];
            }

            if (!skip)
                results[n++] = combo;
        }

        return results;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        string[][] results = GetJoinCombinations(new string[][]
        {
            new string[] { "1", "2", "3" },
            new string[] { "A", "B", "C" },
            new string[] { "+", "-", "*", "/" },
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static IEnumerable<int[]> GetAllPossibleCombos(List<int[]> ints)
        => _getAllPossibleCombos(ints, 0, new List<int>());


    private static IEnumerable<int[]> _getAllPossibleCombos(IReadOnlyList<int[]> ints, int index, IReadOnlyCollection<int> current)
    {
        return index == ints.Count - 1
            ? ints[index]
               .Select(_ => new List<int>(current) {_}.ToArray())
            : ints[index]
               .SelectMany(_ => _getAllPossibleCombos(ints, index + 1, new List<int>(current) {_}));
    }
```